Are these true Sanskrit/English translations of Kamdev mantra?
Kamdev mantra lyrics in Sanskrit:
„Om Kamadevaya Vidmahe Pushpa Baanaya Dhimahi Tanno Ananga Prachodayath.”
Translation in English:
„Om, Let me meditate on the God of love, Oh, God who is the forest of flowers, give me higher intellect, and let the God of love illuminate my mind. ”

Pushpa-Bana means the arrrow made of flowers which is missing in the above translation.
Word by word Translation:
Kaamadevaaya – Unto Kamadeva (God of Love).
Vidmahe – I understand / know
Pushpa Banaya – Unto the One with the flower-laden arrow
Dheemahi – I meditate upon
Tanno – He unto me
Ananga – Cupid
Prachodayaat – Inspire / awaken
Full translation:
I meditate on Kamadeva, the God of Love. I deeply contemplate upon Him who wields the bow of flowers. May that Ananga (the bodiless one or Cupid) inspire or awaken me.

Thank you so much! It finally makes sense!!

Happy to help!! You can upvote / accept the answer.

Is that the Vote Up?
